# ZK generate button with listener pointing to a Composer's method

Tags: events, onclick, event-listener, zk

I'm working with ZK Framework and I need to generate a `<listbox>` with an 'ListItemRenderer' I'm implementing. The problem is that I need to generate a button inside the renderer pointing to a Composer's method with the `onClick` event. Here is the code:

#### ZUL

```
<window id="mywin" apply="pkg.MyComposer">
    <listbox id="mylbx"
        model="@{mywin$MyComposer.action}"
        itemRenderer="pkg.MyRenderer">
        <listhead>
            <listheader .../>
            ...
        </listhead>
    </listbox>
    ...
</window>
```

#### Composer

```
package pkg

public class MyComposer extends SelectorComposer<Window> {

    @Wire("#mylbx")
    private Listbox listbox;

    public void action() {
        // do some work, added a breakpoint in the first statement
    }
```

#### Renderer

```
package pkg

public class MyRenderer implements ListitemRenderer<MyItem> {

    @Override
    public void render(Listitem item, MyItem data, int index) throws Exception {
        // Some rendering...

        Listcell actionCell = new Listcell();
        this.addButton(actionCell, "Action 1", "btn_action1", index, "50%",
                "onClick=mywin$MyComposer.action");
        // another button (doesn't matter) ...
        actionCell.setParent(item);

    }

    private void addButton(Listcell parent, 
            String label, 
            String id, 
            int index, 
            String width,
            String forwardAction) {
        Button btn = new Button(label);
        btn.setId(id + "_" + index);
        btn.setClass(id); // Second try
        btn.setWidth(width);
        ComponentsCtrl.applyForward(btn, forwardAction); // First try
        btn.setParent(parent);
    }
}
```

To test if `action()` is called, I added a breakpoint with my IDE in the first statement of the method, as I say in the comment.

My first try was to add a forward action in `addButton()`. I took that from another renderer where it was applied to a `Span` component, but `action()` was never called.

The second try was to define a `class` attribute for the button (so every button of the same type gets the same class) and to add an annotation to `action()` like this:

```
@Listen("onClick = .btn_action1")
public void actiion() {...}
```

but the result is the same.

I'm thinking that I need to add an `EventListener` to the button or to the composer but I don't know how to point to the correct method between the composer and the renderer.

Any help and/or guide is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make this generic is to make a constructor who takes the composer as argument.
Of course, not every composer has that method so you need to create a interface what you will set on the composer.

```
public interface ButtonListboxRenderer {
    void onClickListboxButton(); // of course with return type and arguments you need.
}
```

Then your renderer :

```
public class MyRenderer implements ListitemRenderer<MyItem> {
    private final ButtonListboxRenderer composer;

    public MyRenderer(ButtonListboxRenderer composer) {
        this.composer = composer;
    }

    ...



  private void addButton(Listcell parent, 
            String label, 
            String id, 
            int index, 
            String width,
            String forwardAction) {
        Button btn = new Button(label);
        btn.setId(id + "_" + index);
        btn.setClass(id); // Second try
        btn.setWidth(width);
        // add eventlistener to the button and you can point to the method of the composer.
        btn.setParent(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a point there. Shouldn’t be `private SelectorComposer<Window> composer` instead of a custom interface? How do you inyect the composer in the renderer? I mean: you declare the renderer in the ZUL but you need to specify the composer, isn’t it?

Comment: You can attach the renderer in the composer. If you use selectorcomposer, you can't call your method because selectorcomposer doesn't know your custom method.